# Textbox data Output

Tags: vb.net

Good day im having some trouble with my code

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Tab Then

        checkoperator()
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        SendKeys.Send("{BACKSPACE}")
        If lbloperatorb.Text = "" Then
            TextBox1.Text = ""
            MsgBox("User ID does not exist.")
            lbloperatorb.Text = ""
            TextBox1.Focus()
        Else
            TextBox1.Text = lbloperatorb.Text
            TextBox1.Enabled = False
        End If

        cmbmodel1.Focus()

    End If

End Sub

  Public Sub checkoperator()

    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
    cmd.Connection = conn
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT empname FROM tbluser where userid= '" + TextBox1.Text + "'"
    lbloperatorb.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar

End Sub
```

When im using tab as my "ENTER" and pasting query at my text box here's what i got

[image: sample photo. with tab before my text]

i already tried to delete the textbox before sending data. but nothing happen

Comment: Please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem.  Your current description is far too vague.

Comment: First you need to Enter your employee id
then press tab
after that it will search at database and append name to same textbox.
but when i press tab as you can see theres a `tab` before the name.

i ready set my textbox empty before appending my queried data at my textbox but as you can see theres a TAB before the name

Comment: If I just add a `TextBox` control and hit the `Tab` key, the `KeyDown` event doesn't detect it at all and focus just shifts to the next control in the Tab order.  Apparently you don't know what "full" means.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `KeyDown`, use the `Leave` event. The following code will then work.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Leave

    checkoperator()
    'TextBox1.Text = ""
    'SendKeys.Send("{BACKSPACE}")
    If lbloperatorb.Text = "" Then
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        MsgBox("User ID does not exist.")
        lbloperatorb.Text = ""
        TextBox1.Focus()
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = lbloperatorb.Text
        TextBox1.Enabled = False
        lbloperatorb.Text = ""
    End If

    'lbloperatorb.Focus()

End Sub
```